# LoginImageUrl not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer, master-pages, loginstatus

I'm trying to add images for login and logout to a `LoginStatus` control in my `Site.master` with the following code:

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LoginImageUrl="~/ICONS/Login.png" LogoutImageUrl="~/ICONS/Logout.png" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/>
```

This works fine for the `LogoutImageUrl` (i.e. the image is displayed as expected) but not for the `LoginImageUrl` (no image displayed, just the standard `LoginStatus`). The image is definitely in the target location.

Comment: what does mean "works"?

Comment: @majidgeek: I mean an image is displayed as expected.

Comment: Maybe when logged-in, client has access to image but inaccessible for not-logged-in clients. What's the permission for anonymous clients on that folder?

Comment: Don't think it can be a permission issue. There are icons displaying elsewhere on same page from the same folder when not logged in.

Comment: Does my answer works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your image extension is in uppercase!

Comment: Thanks. This helped me find a workaround: `<AnonymousTemplate>
                         <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">
                             <img src="ICONS/Login.png" /></a> 
                    </AnonymousTemplate>`